# Validation using jQuery from populated keys and labels using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi want to use jquery validation to validate my fields. I currently have my keys and labels populated by my ajax command.

What would be the best way going about this, I dont want to use the plugin if possible.

I currently have this for all my statments which works to check if the field is blank, however i would I improve this to ensure fields could only have numbers letter etc?

```
if ($("#data").val() == "" ) {
    eMessage = "error";
    valid = false;
}
if ( !valid && errorMessage.length > 0){
    alert(eMessage);
};
});
```

Comment: It depends on your values. For example if you have a phone number, you may need to check the value by regex string. There are lots of validation function in JQuery. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: So for example my first ID from the json file is Firstname, how can i go about adding to that statement to only allow characters to be added into the textbox?